# is it possible to change class into div in media-query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

**My CSS code**

```
[class*="nav"] {width: 100%; }
    @media only screen and (min-width=1024px) {
    .nav {width= 38%;}
}
```

is it possible to change `[class*="nav"]` into `[div*="nav"]`

Comment: Show us the markup. Do you mean to change to _div with class that start with nav_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct, the `[class*="nav"]` is an attribute selector and the *class* is the name of the attribute to target, in this case `class`, so if you want this to apply to a `div` and not to any other type of elements, containing `nav` in its class, you do like this

```css
[class*="nav"] {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
    div[class*="nav"] { width: 38%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">A div</div>
<span class="nav-item">A span</span>
```

*Note, I changed your equal sign `=` in your @media rules to color `:`*

Answer (score 0):

`[class*="nav"]` finds all the elements with class `nav` or that have classes that contain the name `nav` .

see example ( both divs take the css styles )

```css
[class*="nav"] { height:100px;width:100px;background:red;margin:10px 0}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar"></div>
<div class="nav"></div>
```

`[div*="nav"]` does not exist . `nav` is a HTML tag just like a `div` . they are two different tags

```css
div { width:100px;height:100px;background:red;}
nav { width:100px;height:100px;background:blue;}
```

```html
<div></div>
<nav></nav>
```

**SOLUTION**:

**1** if you want to select only the `nav` tags, just use

```
nav { /*styles here*/ }
```

**2** if you want to select only the `div` tags that have classes with `nav` then use

```
div[class*="nav"] {/*styles here*/}
```

**useful links**

- [Nav tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp)
- [Div tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax might be the issue. Try:

```
div[class*="nav"] {
   width: 100%; 
}
// You could also just use .nav above, depending on how your elements are named.
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
 .nav {
   width: 38%;
 }
}
```

Comment: it seems this should be the best